# i need to auto resize the other views while dragging a particular view on a Parent View

Tags: objective-c

I'm sub viewing four or five Views on a Parent View. And i want resize the other Views while editing a particular view using touch methods. If i touch and drag a particular view to the right , the view which is in the right side have resize automatically. This is the requirement for all the sides while dragging a View (Right,Left,Top,Bottom). Any suggestion.
thanks.

Comment: if you are on working on ios7 then use autolayout (set constraints) for each subview.

Comment: No Mano i'm not using ios 7...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this is exactly what you are asking for, but maybe it helps.
You can use touchesMoved method to find out where you are dragging your view (which direction):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];

    if (location.x - prevLocation.x > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"resize right view");
    }
    else if (location.x - prevLocation.x < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"resize left view");
    }
    if (location.y - prevLocation.y > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"resize bottom view");
    }
    else if (location.y - prevLocation.y < 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"resize top view");
    }
}
```

Probably you have to add some bool variable which tell you do you drag any view and when you do change the frame.

Comment: And also i'm having two views at the same axis.so i need to resize the both views.

Comment: You can do for example when you drag in the x axis and the x point is greater that (view.frame.size.width / 2) resize the right view otherwise resize left. The same do for top/bottom just compare y against view height point.